# Android how to pass value from async task to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

In My Android Project I am using **TabLayout**,I have

```
Fragment1   --> Fragment2(AlertDialog)
           |
 button1---      name:
 listview        Id:
               okButton--->AsyncTask
```

Here,In **Fragment1** after pressing **button1** calls another **fragment(Fragment2)**, there after fillup the form pressing **okbutton** calls **AsyncTask** to receive data from server.then the data needs to display in **Fragment1's

 listview**

My classes:

**interface**

```
public interface TaskCompleted {
        // Define data you like to return from AysncTask
        public void onTaskComplete(Integer result);
}
```

**Fragment1**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements TaskCompleted {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment picker = new SearchFragment();
                picker.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                 }
        });

        return view;
    }

public static void submit(final String serverResponse) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        final class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {



            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {

                    //code to process response



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

                //display into adapter

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment2**

```
public class Fragment2 extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);

        builder.setView(content);
        builder.setMessage("form")
                // Positive button
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        new JSONfunctions(getActivity()).execute();
                    }
                });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String serverResponse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class JSONfunctions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private TaskCompleted mCallback;
public JSONfunctions(Context context){
this.mContext = context;
 this.mCallback = (TaskCompleted) context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

String serverResponse="";
try {
====code to connect to server===

return serverResponse; (return result)
}

}  catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return serverResponse;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
 mCallback.onTaskComplete(result);
}   
}
```

and in **MainActivity** I also have

```
@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String serverResponse) {
    Fragment2.submit(serverResponse); 
    }
```

With this code from **fragment2** after pressing **okbutton** it calls **asyncTask**
and gets successfull response from server..but not displaying into listview..Why?????

Comment: ListView is in Fragment or in Activity?

Comment: listview In Fragment1

Comment: Preeti, from where you are adding `Fragment2 ` Fragment? and also add logs in `onTaskComplete ` method of `MainActivity `  check `onTaskComplete` method is called or not

Comment: I'm using viewpager tablayout. where Fragment1 is one tab..from Fragment1 I'm calling Fragment2 as alert dialog.from alert dialog I am calling asynctask..Now i want to display async task value to Fragment1's listview

Comment: ok and `onTaskComplete ` method is called or not in MainActivity ?

Comment: Yes, It is called..Ihave added the code inside mainActivity:---    public void onTaskComplete(String serverResponse) {
    Fragment2.submit(serverResponse); 
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113476/discussion-between--k-and-preeti).

Comment: if possible then share demo code link

Answer (score 0):

Such a complex scenario implemented for such a simple task.
All you need to do is let the Fragment1 implement TaskCompleted interface and create AsyncTask in a separate class and make an attribute of TaskCompleted in this task.

When in onPostExecute just call the listener function and one thing more you have to pass the fragment reference to your async task while creating its object in constructor.

```
final class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        //your attributes
         TaskCompleted listener;

        public DownloadJSON(TaskCompleted listener){
          this.listener = listener;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {

                jsonarray = new JSONArray(serverResponse);
                Gson gson = new Gson();


                User[] user = gson.fromJson(jsonarray.toString(), User[].class);

                // Contact con = new Contact();
                for (int i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("name", user[i].getFullname());
                    map.put("id", user[i].getId());
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            listener.onTaskCompleted(arraylist);

        }
    }

   public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements TaskCompleted {

       @Override
       public void onTaskComplete(ArraList<YourListModel> data) {
         adapter = new ListViewAdapter(activity, data);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }
```

Also apply null checks where necessary.